# Create a custom worksheet function in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have a faint memory of being able to use VBA functions to calculate values in Excel, like this (as the cell formula):

```
=MyCustomFunction(A3)
```

Can this be done?

EDIT:

This is my VBA function signature:

```
Public Function MyCustomFunction(str As String) As String
```

The function sits in the `ThisWorkbook` module. If I try to use it in the worksheet as shown above, I get the `#NAME?` error.

---

Solution (Thanks, codeape): The function is not accessible when it is defined `ThisWorkbook` module. It must be in a "proper" module, one that has been added manually to the workbook.

Comment: It's worth noting that newer versions of Excel have VBA disabled if you save the workbook with an .xlsx extension.  You need to save it with an .xlsm extension for VBA to be enabled.

Comment: You probably also need to save the worksheet file if you did not already. Then closing and opening it again might do the thing. Yet again, you might need to re-apply your formula in case you've changed it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes it can. You simply define a VBA function in a module. See http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/user-defined-functions.html for a nice introduction with examples.

Here's a simple example:

- Create a new workbook
- Switch to VBA view (Alt-F11)
- Insert a module: Insert | Module
- Module contents:

```
Option Explicit

Function MyCustomFunction(input)
    MyCustomFunction = 42 + input
End Function
```

- Switch back to worksheet (Alt-F11), and enter some values:

```
A1: 2
A2: =MyCustomFunction(A1)
```

Comment: Hm, seems my choice of module was wrong. It must not sit in the ThisWorkbook module, but in a separate one. Thanks. :)

Comment: Your function signature is wrong. Use "untyped" arguments and return values. I don't remember what VBA actually does when you leave out the type, it uses the Variant type, I guess.

Comment: I am actually not sure if the signature *is* wrong. I haven't tested. But anyway I guess it is best to use variants - since then you can use the function with both cell references (passed as Range objects) and constants (passed as Float, string, whatever).

Comment: Since this is going to be a quick-and-dirty throwaway solution, passing in a string will be sufficient. But I'll think of it the next time I need it. :)

Comment: Arguments may be typed or untyped (Variants), both ways ()and mixtures) work. If type is specified, Excel/VBA will work to try to coerce the input into that specified, which may be a good thing, may not.

Answer (score 4):

The word input needs to be replaced as it is a basic keyword. Try num instead. You can also go further by specifying a type, eg variant.

```
Function MyCustomFunction(num As Variant)
    MyCustomFunction = 42 + num
End Function
```