# Get A Function's Return Value From Run

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, return-value

I am running an Excel Macro from an Outlook Macro, and I need to get the Excel Macro's return.

My Outlook Macro's code looks like this:

```
Dim excelApp As Object

Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excelApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\meej\Documents\Book1.xlsm"

If excelApp.Run("ThisWorkbook.Foo", true) Then
    Debug.Print "TRUE"
Else
    Debug.Print "FALSE"
End If
excelApp.Quit
Set excelApp = Nothing
```

My Excel Macro looks like this:

```
Public Function Foo(ByVal result as Boolean) as Boolean
    Foo = result
    MsgBox Foo
End Function
```

My `MsgBox` pops up and shows true but in Outlook I always print "FALSE". Am I misusing `Run`?

Comment: From what I gather you are using Run properly as it will return a boolean which is what the if statement wants. The issue might lie in the `result` not being cast correctly.

Comment: @Matt Hmmm... but I'm seeing it print from the `MsgBox` correctly?

Comment: Might be on the wrong track but what is the result of this `MsgBox VarType(result)` inside your function

Comment: @Matt It just pops up a Message Box that says "True".

Comment: I just tested your code in outlook calling an excel document. The only thing different between what you did and what i did is that my call in `Run` was `"Module1.Foo", False`. My Immediate window printed properly.

Comment: I also just found this which might be pertinnent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755812/create-a-custom-worksheet-function-in-excel-vba

Comment: @Matt oh snap! that was it! I don't know why `Module1` works but the workbook doesn't. If you post that as an answer I will happily accept it. I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somone else might have a more verbose answer but in short your logic is sound. Ive always had issues with calling custom functions from `ThisWorkbook`. Using your exact code I was able to get this working by moving the code into a module

```
If excelApp.Run("Module1.Foo", true) Then
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755812/create-a-custom-worksheet-function-in-excel-vba) shows a similar issue trying to use functions from `ThisWorkbook` as formulas

Comment: I have another question floating around for `UsedRange`, it seems like `ThisWorkbook` might just fall into the same: "Just don't use it" category. I sure would like to know _why_ Microsoft has stuff in there that just doesn't work as advertised.

Comment: @JonathanMee ThisWorkbook i think is more for the work book event if nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

I used the Application.Run method in the context of Excel and MS Project. There seems to be no way to trigger a FUNCTION from Excel within a MS Project file rather than trigger a method. Later on i found a work around for letting Excel communicate with MS-Project:

**FROM Excel:**

```
Function doSomethingInProject()

 Dim params(0 To 1) As String
 params(0) = "Some param"
 params(1) = "RETURN_VALUE"

 Dim prj As Object
 Set prj = CreateObject("msproject.application")

 prj.FileOpen Name:=filename, ReadOnly:=False, FormatID:="MSProject.MPP"
 prj.Application.Run "runTheMethod", params

 prj.FileSave
 prj.FileClose
 prj.Quit

 Msgbox "return value is " & params(1)

End Function
```

**WITHIN Project:**

```
Sub runTheMethod(ByRef params)

 'do stuff with params(0)
 params(1) = "Return any value"

End Sub
```

I hope that helps someone, for me it took a bit of time to figure that out :)

Best regards

Joerg