# How do Iinvoke a VBA function inside a Worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple VBA function that is saved in ThisWorkbook of a trusted Macro-Enabled Workbook.  The code for this function: `GetParameterKey` is below.

I would like to call `GetParameterKey` as a spreadsheet function from a worksheet in the same workbook.  However, `GetParameterKey` does not appear as a user-defined function under Insert Function.

Is there a way to call a function that is defined in the ThisWorkbook section from a worksheet in the same workbook?

```
Public Function GetParameterKey(natureOfWork As String, size As String, complexity As String, uncertainty As String) As String
'
' GetParameterKey Macro
' Computes a VLOOKUP key for Nature of Work, Size, Complexity, and Uncertainty.
'
    Select Case UCase(Trim(natureOfWork))

        Case "BACK END"
            GetParameterKey = "1"

        Case "FRONT END"
            GetParameterKey = "2"

        Case "BOTH"
            GetParameterKey = "3"

        Case Else
            GetParameterKey = "0"

    End Select

    GetParameterKey = GetParameterKey & CategoryKey(size)
    GetParameterKey = GetParameterKey & CategoryKey(complexity)
    GetParameterKey = GetParameterKey & CategoryKey(uncertainty)

End Function

Function CategoryKey(category As String) As String

    Select Case UCase(Trim(category))

        Case "VERY LARGE"
            CategoryKey = "5"

        Case "LARGE"
            CategoryKey = "4"

        Case "MEDIUM"
            CategoryKey = "3"

        Case "SMALL"
            CategoryKey = "2"

        Case Else
            CategoryKey = "1"

    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a custom worksheet function in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755812/create-a-custom-worksheet-function-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning value from excel macro vba function is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56095310/returning-value-from-excel-macro-vba-function-is-always-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the function in a separate module instead.

1. Insert -> Module
2. Paste the function there (make sure it's declared as `Public`)
3. And you should be able to call it from worksheet now

[image]
[image]